# Normal distribution around N

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have not done stats for several years and seem to have forgotten the basics.

I am trying to find the standard deviation of a normal distribution given a desired mean and cumulative probability between $a \in \mathbb R$ and $b \in \mathbb R$, with $a < b$.

For example, if I want $\mu = 5, a = 0, b = 10, \text{cumulative(a,b) = 98.76%}$, I would get $\sigma = 2$ ($\text{cumulative(a,b)}$ is the cumulative probabilty from $a$ to $b$). The distribution looks like this:

[image: normal distribution]

Right now, I am using http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html and by trial and error (changing standard deviation and looking at resulting probability) to get desired standard deviation.

What is a formula I can use to get $\sigma$ of a normal distribution such that the probability between $a \in \mathbb R$ and $b \in \mathbb R$, with $a < b$ is $x \in [0,1]$?

Answer (score 1):

If you know what $\operatorname{cumulative}(-\infty,a)$ or $\operatorname{cumulative}(-\infty,b)$ is, you can find $\sigma$ through standardizing your distribution. Consider the standard normal distribution, $Z\sim N(0,1)$ (i.e. a normal distribution with $\mu=0$,$\sigma=1$).

Now, $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$. In other words, $\operatorname{invornm}(\operatorname{cumulative}(-\infty,a))=\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}$. Repeating this with $b$, we get a pair of equations which we can use to solve for $\sigma$. This technique is known as standardizing the normal distribution.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in your second paragraph, I would get $x_1 = \frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}$ and $x_2 = \frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}$ where $a,b,\mu,x_1,x_2$ are known. The only unknown is $\sigma$. How would I use these two equations to solve for $\sigma$? They both give different values for $\sigma$.

Comment: $\sigma=\frac{a-\mu}{x_1}$ and $\sigma=\frac{b-\mu}{x_2}$. You should get the same value of $\sigma$ for both. Taking the distribution in your question which is $N(5,\sigma^2)$, to find $\sigma$ given $\operatorname{cumulative}(0,10)=0.9876$; we know that this is symmetric about $\mu=5$, meaning that $\operatorname{cumulative}(-\infty,0)=$\operatorname{cumulative}(10,\infty)=\frac{1-0.9876}{2}=0.0062$$. We therefore have $-2.501=\frac{0-5}{\sigma}$ and $2.501=\frac{10-5}{\sigma}$, which gives us $\sigma=2$.

Comment: With $\mu-a=b-\mu$, it is easy to get $cumulative(-\infty,a)$ and $cumulative(-\infty,b)$ (as you have shown). However, is there a way to get $cumulative(-\infty,a)$ and $cumulative(-\infty,b)$ where the distance from the mean to $a$ and $b$ are different?

Answer (score 0):

In the more general situation: You need to know two (separate) probabilities $P(X \le a)$ and $P(X \le b)$ for two given numerical values $a$ and $b.$ Then standardizing you can get numerical values for $(a - \mu)/\sigma$ and for $(b - \mu)/\sigma$ from printed normal tables and solve the two equations for $\mu$ and $\sigma,$ in terms of $a,b,$ and those two numerical values.

In your specific problem you could use $\mu$ as the median, giving one of the two probabilities as $0.5,$ then get the probability corresponding to either $a$ or $b,$ using symmetry.